# How to access variables inside a movie clip on the main timeline?

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok so i have some variables called "stat" that is inside a movie clip that i need to access from the main timeline. I have tried multiple ways but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edited.

I put the stage instance Movieclip names "mc". and this is have a this script.

```
var stat:String ="Test";
```

and next following script, Main timeline. If you access `mc.stat` you not get value. console show to `null`. when you called In Main timeline script access to instance MovieClip inner variable. because maybe Initialization code inside the script does not work yet. so you should delay called.

I suggested Using the `Timer`. try this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

trace("check1:" + mc.stat);

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1, 1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onAdded);
timer.start();

function onAdded(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onAdded);
    trace("check2:" + mc.stat);
}
```

Comment: for some reason it never makes the second check

Comment: i created the variable like this inside the movieclip

var stat:Number = 1;

Comment: ok it only makes the trace when i select another window and then select it again

Comment: why? occur error? or? this syntax right? `trace("check2:" + mc.stat);` I edited.

Comment: it only makes the 2nd trace after deselecting then selecting the window again it also traces the right value

Comment: Yes, you're right. So, any other suggestions on how to. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Code is always helpfull!
The movieclip musst exist at the time the code is executed.

```
trace("stat value in mc = " + mcName.stat);
```

Comment: for mcName do i put the instance name or the actal movieclip name?

Comment: it says that access of undefined property

Comment: when and where are you creating the stat value?! pls show some code.
like i said, the mc musst exist before the call

Comment: ok i fixed that it was a typo, i am creating the stat variable inside a movie clip on exactly the same frame as the place i am trying to use it on the main timeline, now i get NaN

Comment: how and where do you create var stat ?

Comment: then no value has been asigned to it. have you got frames in your mc?

Comment: i create stat like this




var stat:Number = 1;

an it only have one frame in the mc