# Find Variable Inside Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a movieclip that is supposed to control all of that specific movieclip's motion (it is the main character and it moves with arrow keys, and I made the event listeners inside the movieclip). I also set up a VCam to follow this movieclip. Something annoying about the VCam, however, is that is becomes jolty when following the movieclip, I think because it is moving once every 1/30 seconds while the movieclip is moving constantly. That may be incorrect, though.

I know how to reference the root code from the movieclip's timeline, but how do you reference a variable in the movieclip's timeline in the main timeline? I want the VCam to have the exact motion of the object, so I will apply the same variable to the VCam, for speed, as I did to the movieclip.

I do not have any code to show, because this is about terminology and syntax, but if you think this is a dumb idea for moving a vcam and want to suggest otherwise, feel free to do so.

If I am explaining this horribly, let me know and I will fix it.

Comment: I honestly don't think there is a way to do this. Sorry

Comment: What exactly is in the movie clips main timeline that you need access to? There will almost certainly be a way to accomplish your goal without spilling your code all over different timelines. Timeline coding is for animators, not game developers.

Comment: what about creating some function, say, `updateVCam` in the root code and calling it from the character timeline passing all the data you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access variables inside a movie clip on the main timeline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310313/how-to-access-variables-inside-a-movie-clip-on-the-main-timeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call your movieclip with instance name and then its variable

"Mc.var"

You must make it in the first frame and force your character to reach it once
Mc.gotoAndStop(1)
Then make sure you have your animations beginning from second frame and don't let your character returning to first frame again.

A better way :

Go to library window.
Find your movieclip and own a linkage name for it.
Right click on it then select edit class
Now declare your variables public even public static.

save your movieclip class and use it in your main class which would be created too, 
For it: go to properties window, under public section, there is a field named Class. Press the pen icon in front of the field, name your main class and save it too.

Comment: this worked but didn't fix the vcam :/. The VCam looks fine, but the overlay I put on the vcam looks bad. I might just attach an overlay to the main character.

Comment: is it possible to only use an EnterFrame EventListener and inside it pass your movieclip location to Vcam for each frame that your application render? and also make sure your coordinates are correctly  selected, local position and global position are not same